# Callback function not working in POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js

İ'm using Node.js , ExpressJS(5.0.0-alpha.1) and request module

This is POST request

```
 app.post('/generateTags', function(req, res) {
    var title = req.body.title;
    restApiKeywords(title, function(tags) {
      console.log(tags);
    });
    });
  });
```

My callback function;

```
function restApiKeywords(postTitle,callback){
                request_('blabla'+postTitle,{json:true,encoding: "binary"}, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                         var data = body[1];             
                if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {callback(data);} 
         }
    });
    }
```

if i call this function in GET method, it is working;

```
app.get("/test",function(req, res) {
 restApiKeywords("Recep Niyaz", function(tags) {
      console.log(tags);
   });
});
```

How can i run this fuction into POST request basically ?

FİXED:it is my stupid issue , i created two same post method on same project  , sorry my friends :)

Comment: How are you testing your `POST` request? Are submitting some `html` form? Are you using a Chrome app like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)? Or are you sending it through `curl`?

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: Have you checked the `error || response.statusCode != 200` condition?

Comment: i'am submitting with jquery.ajax.post method "$.post"

Comment: Oh my Allah :D :D :D :D , i added this post method two time in my project , i searched "/generateTags" in our files and i get two same post method , dear firiends sorry about that , i was trying to fix this issue over 2 hour , after that i asked  , sorry :)